Ubuntu 24.04 kills all the running processes and logs me out
This question may be duplicate of this, but since it doesn't have an answer I am asking again.
I am running a not so memory intensive deep learning code. After some time, the screen blanks out and I am headed back to the log-in screen again. This is not specific to just coding. This issue is persistent with any small activity running for some time when the system is idle. Can any one tell me the cause.
If any output or particular logs need be shared, I can share theme here. Regards.
Edit 1:
/var/crash is empty. I am sorry I do not understand the second query by @user10489. However I am adding a google drive link of the video which shows the problem that I am facing. This link is here.
Edit 2:
(base) bvrk@bvrk-ws1:~$ journalctl -b --grep=oom
Dec 28 17:01:39 bvrk-ws1 systemd[1]: Listening on systemd-oomd.socket - Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer Socket.
Dec 28 17:02:13 bvrk-ws1 systemd[1]: Starting systemd-oomd.service - Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer...
Dec 28 17:02:13 bvrk-ws1 systemd[1]: Started systemd-oomd.service - Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer.
Dec 28 19:42:00 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: wireplumber.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:42:00 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: wireplumber.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Dec 28 19:42:00 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: dbus.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: dbus.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: gvfs-daemon.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: gvfs-daemon.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: gnome-session-manager@ubuntu.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: evolution-source-registry.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: evolution-source-registry.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: org.freedesktop.IBus.session.GNOME.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: org.freedesktop.IBus.session.GNOME.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.service: systemd-oomd killed 1 process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software-4ccfc3c2-eae0-42b9-9914-c8d9ec09c175.scope: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software-4ccfc3c2-eae0-42b9-9914-c8d9ec09c175.scope: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: gnome-terminal-server.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: vte-spawn-5f0bb206-ee2f-4731-b050-c1469e069354.scope: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: vte-spawn-5f0bb206-ee2f-4731-b050-c1469e069354.scope: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: snap.firefox.firefox-e24dd381-7155-47da-b567-6ae7c5abbb3f.scope: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: snap.firefox.firefox-e24dd381-7155-47da-b567-6ae7c5abbb3f.scope: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: app-gnome-org.gnome.Evolution\x2dalarm\x2dnotify-3048.scope: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: app-gnome-org.gnome.Evolution\x2dalarm\x2dnotify-3048.scope: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: app-gnome-anydesk_global_tray-3066.scope: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: app-gnome-anydesk_global_tray-3066.scope: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: gnome-session-manager@ubuntu.service: Failed with result 'oom-kill'.
Dec 28 19:58:41 bvrk-ws1 systemd[15113]: org.freedesktop.IBus.session.GNOME.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.

Additionally,
(base) bvrk@bvrk-ws1:~$ journalctl -b --grep=systemd-oomd
Dec 28 17:01:39 bvrk-ws1 systemd[1]: Listening on systemd-oomd.socket - Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer Socket.
Dec 28 17:02:13 bvrk-ws1 systemd[1]: Starting systemd-oomd.service - Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer...
Dec 28 17:02:13 bvrk-ws1 systemd[1]: Started systemd-oomd.service - Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer.
Dec 28 19:42:00 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: wireplumber.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:42:00 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: dbus.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: gvfs-daemon.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: gnome-session-manager@ubuntu.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: org.gnome.Shell@x11.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: evolution-source-registry.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: org.freedesktop.IBus.session.GNOME.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.service: systemd-oomd killed 1 process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: tracker-miner-fs-3.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software-4ccfc3c2-eae0-42b9-9914-c8d9ec09c175.scope: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: gnome-terminal-server.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: vte-spawn-5f0bb206-ee2f-4731-b050-c1469e069354.scope: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: snap.firefox.firefox-e24dd381-7155-47da-b567-6ae7c5abbb3f.scope: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: app-gnome-org.gnome.Evolution\x2dalarm\x2dnotify-3048.scope: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:43:30 bvrk-ws1 systemd[2511]: app-gnome-anydesk_global_tray-3066.scope: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.
Dec 28 19:58:41 bvrk-ws1 systemd[15113]: org.freedesktop.IBus.session.GNOME.service: systemd-oomd killed some process(es) in this unit.

Also this:
(base) bvrk@bvrk-ws1:~$ free -h
           total      used     free  shared  buff/cache available
Mem:       31Gi       3.6Gi    8.1Gi  248Mi     20Gi      27Gi
Swap:      15Gi       1.0Gi    14Gi


Some of the same questions in comments from the old question apply here and you didn't put those answers in your question.  1) Is there anything in /var/crash 2) did you check syslog for OOM errors?   I'll add another... can you run top in a window, use f and the arrows to select %mem  (hit space if it doesn't already have a *) and hit s to select it for sorting and then q to return to the main screen and then start your job and watch its memory grow and watch the free memory numbers at the top.  Add the results from any of the above to your question...

Other useful memory columns in top to watch might be VIRT RES SWAP.

Also, make sure you distinguish being logged out from just getting a lock screen after being idle.

@user10489, I have updated the question as per your comment. Regards

Yup, that look like a OOM error, check journalctl -b --grep=oom
journalctl -b --grep=systemd-oomd
